# Fetching Email Signature in apex

Tags: email, email2case

I need to fetch Email signature in apex which is stored in My Settings-->Email-->My Email Settings.

Any approach to fetch it either in vf or apex.

Answer (score 3):

Now we can get signature in apex using this 
`SELECT Id, Signature FROM User`